# Boolean algebra simplifcation

Tags: boolean-algebra

((q IMPLIES p) OR ((r OR q) AND (NOT q OR p) )) AND ((NOT p AND q) IMPLIES r)

how do I simplify this to (p or not q) I'm stumped I have tried applying rules of interference but I just cant get it a simplified form much help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use absorption laws $p\vee (p\wedge q) = p\wedge (p\vee q) = p$ 
(and of course $p\implies q = \neg p\vee q$)

Comment: so if (not q or p) and ((not q or p) or r or q) => (not q or p)?

Comment: Even stronger: (not q or p) <=> (not q or p) and ((not q or p) or r or q)

Comment: Thanks babe thats a lot of help